# How to create a query with JOIN and WHERE or how to make them friends?

Tags: mysql, join

I need to make a query, where there are columns of client's names and their orders per month.
Some clients don't have orders at some months and there fields must have 0.
The problem is, when i use WHERE and OUTER JOIN (no matter which one) at one query*, nessesary zero`s cutteed by WHERE. So how can i solve that?

Descripton of tables are pinned.

```
SELECT name
     , ordering.id_client
     , COUNT(order_date) 
  FROM ordering 
 RIGHT 
 OUTER 
  JOIN client 
    ON client.id_client = ordering.id_client 
 WHERE month(order_date) = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY name;
```

```
**Descripton**: (https://i.imgur.com/TrUGOLW.png)

**Example of my query** (there are 6 notes about clients at my db, showed only 4 of 6):

(https://i.imgur.com/ABP6pP0.png)

**MRE stuff**
Client: create table client(id_client int primary key auto_increment, name var char(50), passport_code int, addr varchar(70));
insert into client values(null, 'Penny Anderson', 6485, 'New Orlean');

Ordering: create table ordering(id_order int primary key auto_increment, id_client int, order_date date, foreign key(id_client) references client(id_client));
insert into ordering values(null, 1, date('2020-05-01'));
```

Comment: Put the condition for the date in the ON clause and remove WHERE: `ON client.id_client = ordering.id_client AND month(order_date) = 1 `

Comment: It works. Thanks for help, sry for lack of information, i just didn't understand, what information u need)

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple left join starting from  client's table

```
    SELECT client.name
         , client.id_client
         , COUNT(order_date) 
      FROM client 
     LEFT JOIN  ordering  ON client.id_client = ordering.id_client 
       AND  month(ordering.order_date) = 1 
     GROUP  BY client.id_client;
```

If the condition for join is related  to the left joined  table then add  this condition in the related  ON clause and not in where otherwise this work as  an inner  join

Comment: id doesn`t help

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample as tabular text  (not as image) and the expected  result (and not only your actula result)  ..  if we don't know the starting data we can' eval the result

Comment: anyway answer updated  with a suggestionn ..  for join clause